# Suppress USB device for use only in program

Tags: c++, windows, usb, device-driver, input-devices

I want to set up a driver of sorts for a USB device - written in C++ - in order to have more control over how its input is handled. The problem is that it has a default function that I don't want, and a different program also manages its input when it's open.

The ideal solution to this would be to have my program make the device not be recognised outside of itself, but I have no idea how to do that. I've been googling possible solutions, but to no avail. I have found an option to suppress the default input, but then the program could still recognise it.

Any help at all is welcome; I only need to know a general method for dealing with this problem, it shouldn't be hard to figure out the details on my own.

P.S.: This is kinda the starting point of my project, so please forgive me for not giving any code as context.

Comment: Your question is OS-specific. Which OS do you plan to use?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I use Windows.

Comment: Can you change `vendorId` and `productId` of your USB device? Do you have control over USB devices firmware?

Comment: I might be able to, but it wouldn't be desired since it'd be better if I could keep the original functions as well to make it simpler for the user. I also don't know if the creator of the hardware allows their firmware to be edited.

Comment: Okay, after reading up a bit: yes, I can control the firmware. I still would prefer a different solution though to properly be able to support other devices in the future.

Comment: Why can't you just close the "different program" that "manages its input when it's open"?

Comment: I need to be able to run it at the same time as my program.